# Javascript MD5 Hash Calculations

Tags: javascript, c#, cryptography, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

Ive been researching and trying to work on this for a couple of days now with not very much luck unfortunately, Im trying to replicate a C# project using Java, so its important that I get the exact same results, which so far I have failed.

In C#:

```
byte[] hash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("sometext"));
```

I've managed to get

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("sometext")
```

To output as intended, trying to break down the steps, but from there no luck, it needs to return in bytes, in an array of 16. Exactly how C# would do it, so I can further manipulate it as intended, this is the only hiccup in the project, as when ive forced the bytes into the array, everything else computes as it should.

Ive tried using CryptoJS

```
CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Utf16.parse(str));
```

And converting to an byte array using

```
function convertWordArrayToUint8Array(wordArray) {
    var len = wordArray.words.length,
        u8_array = new Uint8Array(len << 2),
        offset = 0, word, i
    ;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var word = wordArray.words[i];                

        u8_array[offset++] = word >> 24;
        u8_array[offset++] = (word >> 16) & 0xff;
        u8_array[offset++] = (word >> 8) & 0xff;
        u8_array[offset++] = word & 0xff;                                              
    }
    return u8_array;
}
```

With no luck, maybe the above function is to blame who knows, I'm a little lost and spent alot more time on this than I should have, any help would be great!

Comment: Maybe it's good to look at the output byte array. What values are you getting and what values should it be?

Comment: Post the errors (if any) so we can try to figure out what happened. A good debugger is Chrome's F12, as it allows for the values to be debugged in real time.

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("sometext")` returns a byte array of length 8, not 16. `CryptoJS.enc.Utf16.parse(str)` is obviously not the same encoding. Why not use the obvious `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(str)` instead?